# ViewPager with 2 pages and exoplayer views in both of them

Tags: android, android-viewpager, exoplayer

I have a main viewpager with two view pagers as page one and page two, try to think something like a tiktok feed on both pages but with images and videos. Everything is fine and all, but when the first item of both pages is a video(on start) or when sliding from page one while the video is playing to page two that also has a video, a black overlay of the first page goes on top of the second page video. If i scroll up and down the video is playing ok but if i go back from page two to page one with and again from video to video the same thing happens.

Is it because the exoplayer view has match parent as a width?

One workaround i did was to hide the exoplayer view before sliding to the other page and it works fine but is not very ux friendly, and i dont understand this behaviour. Still it does not solve the issue 100%

One other workaround i tried was to slide up and down really fast, and fixes the issue but creates other problems.

The main question is since viewpager demands match parent in both dimentions, and the two feeds have match parent in both dimentions, why when sliding one feed overlaps the other, how is it possible?